# Count number of double underscores in custom formula in data studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a column of data called Department in data studio that contains words with double underscores:

```
Department
marketing
marketing__analytics
marketing__analytics__app
marketing__analytics__website
```

I am trying to create another column called Department Level that counts the number of underscores for each Department

```
Department                      Department Level
marketing                       0
marketing__analytics            1
marketing__analytics__app       2
marketing__analytics__website   2
```

I don't know how to create the Department Level column using a custom formula.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One approach would be to use the [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below, where `__` represents the phrase being searched:

```
DIVIDE((LENGTH(Department) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(Department, "__", ""))) , LENGTH("__"))
```

To explain the above through the use of pseudocode (using `marketing__analytics__website` as an example):

- `DIVIDE((LENGTH(All Characters) - LENGTH(All Characters Excluding __)) , LENGTH(of __)`

In regards to the calculation, the values at each stage would be:

- `DIVIDE((29 - 25) , 2)`

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/1183fe67-fe3b-4c6a-88a3-16a3263490b5) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sHjt7WNvsIfx1T8vx4Q1nf_cXAAUTCBV8ipMK-uOoZQ/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]